# My Jquery Image won't move

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am working on a jquery animation. I do not have much experience with jquery, but I do know basic syntax.
Here is what I got so far...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Nathan</title>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#N").animate({left:'250px'});
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div id="N" style="margin-left:200px;"><image src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/88/Letter_N-1-.png" height="44" width="44"/></div>
 <image src="http://b68389.medialib.glogster.com/media/3cf5bc6910ded698d225a3be66fb7bec27443f45eaa12ee7d207847f79152a10/bubble-graffiti-alphabet-letter-l.jpg" height="44" width="44"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**I tried to function this:**

```
<div id="N" style="margin-left:200px;"><image src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/88/Letter_N-1-.png" height="44" width="44"/></div>
```

with my jquery script.

When I click the button however the image does not move.

What have I done wrong?

How could I edit the code so that it functions with my `<div id="N"` so it can move my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this give

`position:relative`

Answer (score 3):

Give `position:relative` to your div with id "N":

```
<div id="N" style="position:relative;margin-left:200px;">
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9sxD/1/)

Copy the below code directly into page and it should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#N").animate({'left':'250px'});
  });
});
});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>CLICK</button>
<div id="N" style="position:relative;margin-left:200px;"><image src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/88/Letter_N-1-.png" height="44" width="44"/></div>
 <image src="http://b68389.medialib.glogster.com/media/3cf5bc6910ded698d225a3be66fb7bec27443f45eaa12ee7d207847f79152a10/bubble-graffiti-alphabet-letter-l.jpg" height="44" width="44"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason the fiddles work but when I add margin left or position relative to my actual script it doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried everything. Do you think it may be where I set me `<Script>` elements or `<head>` elements. Because js fiddle puts those automatically in the output for you. Since the fiddles work but the script I have doesn't, could that be it? -  @Zword

Comment: ok i will post the the whole code in 2 minutes.Just try it out

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. I forgot about `<script type=` and the meta information. Well it worked

Answer (score 0):

Set the position via CSS:

```
#N {
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ps3zV/)**

Answer (score 0):

hehe... the solution to that is to add a plus sign

```
      $("#N").animate({margin-left:'+250px'});
```

Comment: This won't work because the `div#N` element is statically positioned. As mentioned elsewhere, he'll need to add `position: relative` to the element.